# Trigger Cloudformation Blue/Green With Image Parameter Change

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

In my Cloudformation template, I am using the blue-green deployment trigger and have the following TaskDefinition

```yaml
TaskDefinition:
  Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
  DependsOn: LogGroup
  Properties:
    Family: "task-family-name"
    NetworkMode: awsvpc
    RequiresCompatibilities: [FARGATE]
    Cpu: 512
    Memory: 1024
    ExecutionRoleArn: arn:aws:iam::579072907853:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole
    TaskRoleArn: !Ref ServiceRole
    ContainerDefinitions:
      - Name: !Ref ServiceName
        Essential: true
        Image: !Ref ImageARN
        PortMappings:
          - ContainerPort: !Ref ContainerPort
        LogConfiguration:
          LogDriver: awslogs
          Options:
            awslogs-region: !Ref AWS::Region
            awslogs-group: !Ref LogGroup
            awslogs-stream-prefix: ecs
        Environment: 
          - Name: RACK_ENV
            Value: !Ref EnvironmentName
```

If I update the stack with a new value for the `ImageARN` parameter, I get the following error

```
'CodeDeployBlueGreenHook' of type AWS::CodeDeploy::BlueGreen failed with message: The submitted template's primary task definition 'TaskDefinition' was never updated. The template's 'AWS::CodeDeployBlueGreen' Transform might be missing or removed
```

If I don't use a parameter but instead use a hardcoded `Image` then update the template it works fine.

Is there a way to use a parameter?

### Example

Below is a full example of a template that has this issue. I change the ImageARN parameter between these two images

```
nginx:1.18.0@sha256:001487e0a8c6abf91351ab45fdb308c0c2b95e8a67260b7ca5cf064462689a9e
```

```
nginx:1.19.4@sha256:aec3f367f48745b280ee2fd8d8469c0c0ec6b9b2fca3cd3e6cff03e1b69ae054
```

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Parameters: 
  Image: 
    Type: String
  CIDRBlock: 
    Type: String
    Default: 192.168.5.0/24
    Description: CIDR block for VPC
  ExecutionRoleARN:
    Type: String

Transform:
  - AWS::CodeDeployBlueGreen

Hooks:
  CodeDeployBlueGreenHook:
    Type: AWS::CodeDeploy::BlueGreen
    Properties:
      TrafficRoutingConfig:
        Type: AllAtOnce
      Applications:
        - Target:
            Type: AWS::ECS::Service
            LogicalID: ECSService
          ECSAttributes:
            TaskDefinitions:
              - TaskDefinition
              - GreenTaskDefinition
            TaskSets:
              - TaskSet
              - GreenTaskSet
            TrafficRouting:
              ProdTrafficRoute:
                Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
                LogicalID: HTTPListener
              TargetGroups:
                - TargetGroup
                - TargetGroupGreen
    
Resources: 
  ALBSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Allow HTTP to load balancer
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 80
        ToPort: 80
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      SecurityGroupEgress:
      - IpProtocol: -1
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0

  FargateSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Allow port 80 to service
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 80
        ToPort: 80
        SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref ALBSecurityGroup
      SecurityGroupEgress:
      - IpProtocol: -1
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0

  LoadBalancer:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      Name: load-balancer
      Type: application
      IpAddressType: ipv4
      Scheme: internet-facing
      SecurityGroups: [!Ref ALBSecurityGroup]
      Subnets: [!Ref Subnet1, !Ref Subnet2]

  HTTPListener:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
        - TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroup
          Type: forward
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref LoadBalancer
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP

  TargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      HealthCheckEnabled: true
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 30
      HealthCheckPath: "/"
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 10
      HealthyThresholdCount: 5
      Name: targetgroup-blue
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP
      TargetType: ip
      UnhealthyThresholdCount: 10
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc

  TargetGroupGreen:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      HealthCheckEnabled: true
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 30
      HealthCheckPath: "/"
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 10
      HealthyThresholdCount: 5
      Name: targetgroup-green
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP
      TargetType: ip
      UnhealthyThresholdCount: 10
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      
  TaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      Family: "task-family-name"
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      RequiresCompatibilities: [FARGATE]
      Cpu: 512
      Memory: 1024
      ExecutionRoleArn: !Ref ExecutionRoleARN
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: Container
          Essential: true
          Image: !Ref Image
          PortMappings:
            - ContainerPort: 80

  TaskSet:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskSet
    Properties:
      Cluster: !Ref ECSCluster
      LaunchType: FARGATE
      NetworkConfiguration:
        AwsVpcConfiguration:
          AssignPublicIp: ENABLED
          SecurityGroups: [!Ref FargateSecurityGroup]
          Subnets: [!Ref Subnet1, !Ref Subnet2]
      Scale:
        Unit: PERCENT
        Value: 100
      Service: !Ref ECSService
      TaskDefinition: !Ref TaskDefinition
      PlatformVersion: LATEST
      LoadBalancers: 
        - ContainerName: Container
          ContainerPort: 80
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroup

  ECSService:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    DependsOn: HTTPListener
    Properties: 
      ServiceName: service
      Cluster: !Ref ECSCluster
      DeploymentController: 
        Type: EXTERNAL
      DesiredCount: 4
      EnableECSManagedTags: true
    
  PrimaryTaskSet:
    Type: 'AWS::ECS::PrimaryTaskSet'
    Properties:
      Cluster: !Ref ECSCluster
      Service: !Ref ECSService
      TaskSetId: !GetAtt 'TaskSet.Id'

  Vpc:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Ref CIDRBlock
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      EnableDnsSupport: true

  Subnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      CidrBlock: !Select [0, !Cidr [!Ref CIDRBlock, 2, 6 ]]
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [0, Fn::GetAZs: !Ref 'AWS::Region']

  Subnet2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      CidrBlock: !Select [1, !Cidr [!Ref CIDRBlock, 2, 6 ]]
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [1, Fn::GetAZs: !Ref 'AWS::Region']

  InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway

  InternetGatewayVPCAssoc:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway

  RouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc

  RouteTableSub1Assoc:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties: 
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref Subnet1

  RouteTableSub2Assoc:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties: 
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref Subnet2

  InternetGatewayRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: InternetGateway
    Properties:
       RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
       DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
       GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway

  ECSCluster:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
    Properties:
      ClusterName: Cluster
      CapacityProviders:
        - FARGATE
      DefaultCapacityProviderStrategy:
        - CapacityProvider: FARGATE
          Weight: 1
```

Comment: I checked what I have in my templates. I use image_digest as part of ImageUrl in the form of `imageUri@image_digest`. From what I recall it was necessary to trigger the deployment. Just using `imageUri` was not working like in your case. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Marcin - I hadn't tried but have just now and it still has the same issue unfortunately

Comment: When you update your image, do you use new `image_digest`?

Comment: I tried having an Image param which was the whole URI+@+digest and I also tried with an ImageURI parameter and separate ImageDigest parameter then joined them with '@' neither worked.

Comment: Can you provide minimal, self-contained working template demonstrating the issue? I can try to replicate the issue, but with those bits and pieces you've posted its difficult.

Comment: @Marcin - I have added an example template for which I experience the error. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at your example, and what I have in my own projects. I can confirm that your example does not work as expected.

I investigated more and determined that the issue is likely to be due to creation of entire networking stack in your template. In my own projects I don't have VPC or subnets in my ecs templates, thus it all works.

So once I removed the VPC related things from your template it started to work as required. There are some other smaller changes, but they may not be necessary. I think the VPC-stuff is the main reason.

Also, please update the template by using **Replace current template** option, rather then `Use current template`. If you use the second option it will still not work. I think this is due to how macros work in CFN, and template should be replaced, rather then updated in-place. If you replace it, B/G in **CodeDeploy is successful trigger** and you can view it CodeDeploy console.

Here is the modified template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Parameters: 

  ImageUrl: 
    Type: String
    
  VpcId:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPC::Id'
    
  Subnet1:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id'
    
  Subnet2:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id'
    
  ExecutionRoleARN:
    Type: String

  DesiredCount:
    Type: Number
    Default: 2
      
    
Transform:
  - 'AWS::CodeDeployBlueGreen'

Hooks:
  CodeDeployBlueGreenHook:
    Type: 'AWS::CodeDeploy::BlueGreen'
    Properties:
      TrafficRoutingConfig:
        Type: AllAtOnce
      Applications:
        - Target:nginx:1.19.4@sha256:aec3f367f48745b280ee2fd8d8469c0c0ec6b9b2fca3cd3e6cff03e1b69ae054
            Type: 'AWS::ECS::Service'
            LogicalID: ECSService
          ECSAttributes:
            TaskDefinitions:
              - TaskDefinition
              - GreenTaskDefinition
            TaskSets:
              - TaskSet
              - GreenTaskSet
            TrafficRouting:
              ProdTrafficRoute:
                Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener'
                LogicalID: HTTPListener
              TargetGroups:
                - TargetGroupnginx:1.19.4@sha256:aec3f367f48745b280ee2fd8d8469c0c0ec6b9b2fca3cd3e6cff03e1b69ae054
                - TargetGroupGreen
    
Resources: 

  ALBSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Allow HTTP to load balancer
      VpcId: !Ref VpcId
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 80
        ToPort: 80
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      SecurityGroupEgress:
      - IpProtocol: -1
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0

  FargateSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Allow port 80 to service
      VpcId: !Ref VpcId
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 80
        ToPort: 80
        SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref ALBSecurityGroup
      SecurityGroupEgress:
      - IpProtocol: -1
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0

  LoadBalancer:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      #Name: load-balancer
      Type: application
      IpAddressType: ipv4
      Scheme: internet-facing
      SecurityGroups: 
        - !Ref ALBSecurityGroup
      Subnets: 
        - !Ref Subnet1
        - !Ref Subnet2

  HTTPListener:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
        - TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroup
          Type: forward
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref LoadBalannginx:1.19.4@sha256:aec3f367f48745b280ee2fd8d8469c0c0ec6b9b2fca3cd3e6cff03e1b69ae054cer
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP

  TargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      HealthCheckEnabled: true
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 30
      HealthCheckPath: "/"
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 10
      HealthyThresholdCount: 5
      #Name: targetgroup-blue
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP
      TargetType: ip
      UnhealthyThresholdCount: 10
      VpcId: !Ref VpcId

  TargetGroupGreen:
    Type: nginx:1.19.4@sha256:aec3f367f48745b280ee2fd8d8469c0c0ec6b9b2fca3cd3e6cff03e1b69ae054AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2nginx:1.19.4@sha256:aec3f367f48745b280ee2fd8d8469c0c0ec6b9b2fca3cd3e6cff03e1b69ae054::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      HealthCheckEnabled: true
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 30
      HealthCheckPath: "/"
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 10
      HealthyThresholdCount: 5
      #Name: targetgroup-green
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP
      TargetType: ip
      UnhealthyThresholdCount: 10
      VpcId: !Ref VpcId
      
  TaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      Family: "task-family-name"
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      RequiresCompatibilities: [FARGATE]
      Cpu: 256
      Memory: 512
      ExecutionRoleArn: !Ref ExecutionRoleARN
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: Container
          Essential: true
          Image: !Ref ImageUrl
          PortMappings:
            - ContainerPort: 80
              Protocol: tcp             

  TaskSet:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskSet
    Properties:
      Cluster: !Ref ECSCluster
      LaunchType: FARGATE
      NetworkConfiguration:
        AwsVpcConfiguration:
          AssignPublicIp: ENABLED
          SecurityGroups: 
            - !Ref FargateSecurityGroup
          Subnets: 
            - !Ref Subnet1 
            - !Ref Subnet2
      Scale:
        Unit: PERCENT
        Value: 100
      Service: !Ref ECSService
      TaskDefinition: !Ref TaskDefinition
      PlatformVersion: LATEST
      LoadBalancers: 
        - ContainerName: Container
          ContainerPort: 80
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroup

  ECSService:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    DependsOn: HTTPListener
    Properties: 
      #ServiceName: service
      Cluster: !Ref ECSCluster
      DeploymentController: 
        Type: EXTERNAL
      DesiredCount: !Ref DesiredCount
      EnableECSManagedTags: true
    
  PrimaryTaskSet:
    Type: 'AWS::ECS::PrimaryTaskSet'
    Properties:
      Cluster: !Ref ECSCluster
      Service: !Ref ECSService
      TaskSetId: !GetAtt TaskSet.Id

  ECSCluster:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
    Properties:
      #ClusterName: Cluster
      CapacityProviders:
        - FARGATE
      DefaultCapacityProviderStrategy:
        - CapacityProvider: FARGATE
          Weight: 1
          
Outputs:
    
  ALBDNSName:
    Value: !GetAtt LoadBalancer.DNSName
```

Comment: In my original template, I wasn't creating the networking stack (that was just for the contained example). The key to the solution was selecting `Replace current template` even though the template hasn't changed. Still not sure why this is exactly - if you know of any references you could add that would be helpful.

Comment: @Josh Thanks. I was searching for some explanation in AWS docs, but couldn't find anything concrete.

Answer (score 0):

When I had this issue the solution was to replace the Image value within a step in the pipeline before the AWS CloudFomration step, basically "building" the file before deployment instead of passing parameters. Is not fancy but it works, I expect there are better solutions to this.

Comment: While I think this would work - the other answer seems to be the correct way of doing this. Hopefully, it helps you too!